# How to pipe anything to the audio output?

Tags: linux, pipe, audio

How can I pipe any data to audio output? For example, i want to listen to a file -- an archive, a drive backup, a program. Or I want to listen to my HDD -- I vaguely remember reading something about this being possible about 7 years ago, but can't find anything now.

So, files, disk reads, even network connections -- I want to be able to listen to anything. I know that it's definitely possible with Linux. How can I do it? Using Lubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I find piping things into `aplay` works well.

`journalctl | aplay` doesn't sound pretty but does work surprisingly well.

Here's an example from [`aplay(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/aplay):

```
aplay -c 1 -t raw -r 22050 -f mu_law foobar
              will play the raw file "foobar" as a 22050-Hz, mono, 8-bit, Mu-Law .au file.
```

It can be found as part of the `alsa-utils` package on debian/ubuntu.

Here's a 1-liner that I like which echos a small C program into gcc, and runs the compiled version, piping it to aplay.  The result is a surprisingly nice 15-minute repeating song.

```
echo "g(i,x,t,o){return((3&x&(i*((3&i>>16?\"BY}6YB6$\":\"Qj}6jQ6%\")[t%8]+51)>>o))<<4);};main(i,n,s){for(i=0;;i++)putchar(g(i,1,n=i>>14,12)+g(i,s=i>>17,n^i>>13,10)+g(i,s/3,n+((i>>11)%3),10)+g(i,s/5,8+n-((i>>10)%3),9));}"|gcc -xc -&&./a.out|aplay
```

Comment: `Here's a 1-liner that I like [...]` Sooo ... just *how* long have you been in lockdown ?-)

Comment: @TomRoche you have to give it a bit of time, it starts out slow then it gets kind of catchy :)

Comment: I first read "... and pipes the compiled version to aplay", and wondered what compiler hacks you were using to get a compiled program sound nice.

Comment: Holy hell, it sounds amazing!!! Oh I'm so glad I asked this question. Have any more?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann actually he does not "pipe" the compiled version like `cat a.out |...`, he runs the program and pipe its output to aplay `./a.out |...`

Comment: @bew yes, I got this on the second read, that's why I wrote "I first read".

Comment: > Got any more?  This one improvises major scale notes using `urandom`: `cat /dev/urandom | hexdump -v -e '/1 "%u\n"' | awk '{ split("0,2,4,5,7,9,11,12",a,","); for (i = 0; i < 1; i+= 0.0001) printf("%08X\n", 100*sin(1382*exp((a[$1 % 8]/12)*log(2))*i)) }' | xxd -r -p | aplay -c 2 -f S32_LE -r 16000
`

Comment: `Cannot open output wave file
aplay: read_header:2950: read error`

Answer (score 11):

It was possible with `/dev/dsp`, which is part of OSS, which hasn't been part of the Linux kernel a very long time. It used to be as easy as `cat some_file >/dev/dsp` or `some_program >/dev/dsp`.

PulseAudio provides `padsp`.

> `padsp` starts the specified program and redirects its access to OSS compatible audio devices (`/dev/dsp` and auxiliary devices) to a PulseAudio sound server.

<sup>([source](https://linux.die.net/man/1/padsp))</sup>

---

Examples:

- random data

  ```
  </dev/urandom padsp tee /dev/dsp >/dev/null
  ```
- regular file

  ```
  </etc/fstab padsp tee /dev/dsp >/dev/null
  ```
- network activity

  ```
  sudo tcpdump | padsp tee /dev/dsp >/dev/null
  ```
- block device

  ```
  sudo cat /dev/sda | padsp tee /dev/dsp >/dev/null
  ```

---

In my Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS `padsp` is from the `pulseaudio-utils` package.

Comment: That's a pretty roundabout way to do what you could equally well do by piping into `pacat`.

Comment: @hobbs Well, I knew `/dev/dsp`, didn't know `pacat`. It seems you can write a good answer.