# Play files as if they were raw audio samples

Tags: linux, utilities

I once in the past used to play with files by playing them as if they were raw 8bit audio, but I forgot which program can be used to do this. How can I stream, say, /dev/random to my speakers with a single command?

Comment: Is `cat file > /dev/dsp` no longer a thing?

Comment: @DopeGhoti not for me, Manjaro user here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/587016/272848https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/587016/272848

Comment: @DopeGhoti I think not: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28045/123460

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe stuff into `aplay` (from the `alsa-utils` debian package).

Example:

```
journalctl -f | aplay
```

will play some noise on your speakers whenever any service writes to the journal.

```
cat /dev/random | aplay
--or--
aplay /dev/random
```

will play random noise.

From [my other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/587016/272848), give this a try ;)

```
echo "g(i,x,t,o){return((3&x&(i*((3&i>>16?\"BY}6YB6$\":\"Qj}6jQ6%\")[t%8]+51)>>o))<<4);};main(i,n,s){for(i=0;;i++)putchar(g(i,1,n=i>>14,12)+g(i,s=i>>17,n^i>>13,10)+g(i,s/3,n+((i>>11)%3),10)+g(i,s/5,8+n-((i>>10)%3),9));}"|gcc -xc -&&./a.out|aplay
```

Answer (score 0):

I remembered, `play` is the utility. Use `-t` to manually override the format it is interpreted as. Usually actual file formats require a header present in the file, so use `fXX` or `uXX` or `iXX` "formats" for raw floating point, unsigned int, signed int sampled audio respectively. Usually `play -t f32 FILENAME` works well enough.

Go ahead, try some files, it'll be interesting. Most compressed files sound like noise (expected), but there's some interesting formats out there which I will let you discover on your own.

Comment: Note: `play` is part of the `sox` package.

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer, but could you add some context so it can be understood? How would we use it? What option, if any, should be given to `-t`? I tried to do this with `play -t wav file` and got an error.

Comment: @terdon addressed! For raw audio you can use the f32, u32 or i32 "types", or the 24, 16, 8 bit versions of those types.